# Recurrence relation in the bisection method

Tags: numerical-methods, recurrence-relations

When beginning to talk about error bounds on the bisection method for root finding, my book states the following:

> Let $a_n$ $b_n$ and $c_n$ denote the $n$th computed values of $a,b,$ and $c$, respectively. Then easily we get 
>   $$
> b_{n+1}-a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(b_{n}-a_{n}),\ n\ge1
> $$
>   and it is straightforward to deduce that 
>   $$
> b_{n}-a_{n}=\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}(b-a),\ n\ge1
> $$
>   where $b-a$ denotes the length of the original interval with which we started.

However, wouldn't it be $b_{n}-a_{n}=\frac{1}{2^{n}}(b-a)$ instead? Simply take $n=1$. As stated, it wouldn't make sense that $b_{1}-a_{1}=(b-a)$, would it?

Comment: Why wouldn't it make sense?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I guess I'm misunderstanding, but shouldn't $b_1-a_1$ half of what the original interval is?

Comment: Why would that be the case? The recurrence is only defined for $n\ge1$, so $b_1-a_1$ isn't half of anything special.

Comment: In the book, they are starting with $a=a_1, b=b_1$ (i.e. indices go up from $1$, not from $0$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Informal statements on sequences are often a little ambiguous.

Sometimes a sequence is thought of as $a_0,a_1,a_2,\cdots$, sometimes as $a_1,a_2,a_3,\cdots$, and when you speak of the $n^{th}$ term, that can be $a_{n-1}$ or $a_n$. Here it is clear that numbering starts at $1$.

But another source of ambiguity is in "*computed* values". Shall we consider that the very first $a,b$ are computed, or are just given ? In the first situation, $a_1=a$. In the second, $a_1$ is a later value (as if $a=a_0$).

---

What we can say for sure: if we start with an interval of length $b-a$ *before* any iteration, every iteration halves that length and *after* $n$ iterations, it becomes $\dfrac{b-a}{2^n}$.

Answer (score -1):

$$a_{n+1}-b_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(a_n-b_n) \implies f_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}f_n$$
One may do multiplicative teslescoping as
$$f_1=\frac{1}{2} f_0$$
$$f_2=\frac{1}{2} f_1$$
$$f_3=\frac{1}{2} f_2$$
$$........$$
$$........$$
$$f_{n-1}=\frac{1}{2} f_{n-2}$$
$$f_n=\frac{1}{2} f_{n-1}$$
Multiplying them, we get
$$\implies f_n=\frac{1}{2^n} f_0, f_0=(a_0-b_0),$$
where $a_0-b_0$ needs to de given.

Comment: -1 I don't think they're asking for a derivation of that, the question is completely different if you read (the question and the comments) closely.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt What I'm asking is why is the exponent $n-1$ rather than $n$? I derived it the same way and I obtained the same result, rather than the one from the book. Why is the book displaying the exponent as $n-1$